# How to properly run and compile an external java source file?

Tags: java

I am new to programming and I would like to compile and run an external java file, that looks like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Test{
    public static int spr1;
    private int spr2;
    public static void main(String[]args){
        System.out.println("Hello world");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(sc.nextInt());
    }
}
```

Is there a simple way (e.g. with ProcessBuilder) to run this program and print an integer from input?

**EDIT:** Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I would like to run an EXTERNAL java program (that looks like that) within a java program. I am currently making a Java editor (with Netbeans) which must compile and run a java program. I am stuck with user input from editorWindow.

**EDIT 2:**
I found the solution. It's pretty simple:

```
ProcessBuilder builderExecute = new ProcessBuilder("java", "Test");
builderExecute.redirectInput(Redirect.INHERIT);
Process p = builderExecute.start();
String line = "";
while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
      System.out.println(line);
```

Comment: `javac Test.java`, followed by `java Test`.  (In a Command Prompt window, of course.)

Comment: To elaborate a bit on Hot Licks comment. Compile the code with the java compiler, and execute the code in anyway you want. Using a ProcessBuilder / Process should work just fine if you want to launch this code from another java process, or use command prompt if you just want to execute it.

Comment: Also you can use and IDE to learn the language (Eclipse, Netbeans,, etc.). They have compilation tools, and it'll be way easier for you

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough: I would like to run an EXTERNAL java program (that looks like that) within a java program. I am currently making a Java editor (with Netbeans) which must compile and run a java program. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: -1. On stack overflow we help people with programming problems, but we don't write programs for you. If you want to try some stuff yourself, and then check back when you have something like a solution, then we'll help with the bits where you're stuck, but you're very unlikely to get a lot of help with questions like, 'please write a large chunk of my app for me'.

Comment: I was just asking for help, for Christs sake.

Answer (score 0):

Execute Java Program within a another Java Program, I hope this is what you are asking for.

You can achieve this using the Process and Runtime classes.

```
import java.io.*;  
public class TestExec {  
    public static void main(String[] args) {  
        try {  
          Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac Test.java");  
            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java Test");  
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(  
                                new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));  
            String line = null;  
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                System.out.println(line);  
            }  
        } catch (IOException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read this [article](http://www.sergiy.ca/how-to-compile-and-launch-java-code-from-command-line/) or [this](http://www.cs.swarthmore.edu/~newhall/unixhelp/debuggingtips_Java.html) , and also you can read help (`javac -help`).

**Update:**
Compile java file programmatically using `ProcessBuilder` .

```
/**
 *
 * @param path
 */
public static void compile(final String path) {
    try {
        final Process sqlProcess = getSqlProcess(path);
                sqlProcess.waitFor();
                if (sqlProcess != null && sqlProcess.exitValue() == 0) {
                    // Done
                    System.out.println("Compilation success");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Compilation fail");
                }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private static Process getSqlProcess(String path) throws Exception {
    if (System.getProperty("os.name").toLowerCase().indexOf("linux") >= 0) {
        path = path.replaceAll("\\s", "\\\\ ");
        String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "javac", path};
        return Runtime.getRuntime().exec(executeCmd);
    } else {
        path = path.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        String[] executeCmd = new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "javac", path};
        return new ProcessBuilder(executeCmd).start();
    }
}
```